# Переход по ссылкам jsoup, jsoup.connect

Tags: java, jsoup

Я подключаюсь, к примеру, к сайту `www.mtis.com`, который имеет ряд дочерних ссылок:

- `www.mtis.com/3114336/razrabotka-ustroystva---kontroller--upravlyaemyiy-element.html`
- `www.mtis.com/311435345336/ustroystva.element.html`

и т.д.

Чтобы парсить дочерние элементы (ссылки) нужно использовать `JSOUP.connect`?
или можно по-другому?

Просто ссылок много и при использовании `JSOUP.connect` программа начинает жутко тормозить.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от того, что Вы понимаете под:

> чтобы парсить дочерние элементы (ссылки)

- если Вам нужно получить список ссылок с какой-либо страницы, то достаточно загрузить только эту страницу;
- если Вам нужно парсить страницы, ссылки на которые находятся на главной странице, то, разумеется, придется загружать все необходимые страницы.